# ClipsToBounds in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've been trying to set `clipsToBounds` in a subclass of `UITableViewCell` to `true` but somehow it becomes `false` again:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        print(contentView.clipsToBounds) // false
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print(contentView.clipsToBounds) // false
    }
}
```

Is there a reason for it to become `false` again in `contentView`? I can "fix" this by setting `clipsToBounds` to `true` in `layoutSubviews()` but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2):

You may try setting the properties in `layoutSubviews()` rather.
You can also use the `awakeFromNib()` function to set the `clipsToBounds` to `true`..

Answer (score 0):

I think the `contentView` will be changed sometimes later after you set `clipsToBounds = true` on `cell.contentView`. Try `cell.clipsToBounds = true` instead.

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: I'm doing everything programmatically so I don't think this would work. And after setting it to true, wouldn't it crash because of the `fatalError`?